# SlidingNumberTile Program Efficiency

Tags: c++, performance, sliding-tile-puzzle

I created a Sliding Number Tile Game, and am looking for input on how to make the code better organized & more efficient.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono> 
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void initializeBoard(char pB[][3]);
void printBoard(char pB[][3], bool truths[][3]);
bool isBoardSolved(char pB[][3], bool truths[][3]);
void slideTile(char pB[][3], char move);
void scrambleBoard(char pB[][3]);

int main()
{
    char pB[3][3];
    bool truths[3][3];

    initializeBoard(pB);
    isBoardSolved(pB, truths);
    printBoard(pB, truths);
    if (isBoardSolved(pB, truths) == true)
    {
        cout << "isBoardSolved(): true" << endl;
    }
    else if (isBoardSolved(pB, truths) == false)
    {
        cout << "isBoardSolved(): false" << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    cout << "Scrambling board..." << endl;
    scrambleBoard(pB);
    isBoardSolved(pB, truths);
    printBoard(pB, truths);
    cout << "Scrambling complete." << endl;
    system("PAUSE");

    system("CLS");
    printBoard(pB, truths);

    char move = ' ';
    bool check = false;
    if (check == true)
    {
        cout << "isBoardSolved(): true" << endl << endl;
    }
    else if (check == false)
    {
        cout << "isBoardSolved(): false" << endl << endl;
    }

    int key = 0;
    while ((move != 27) && (check != true))
    {
        cout << "Use arrow keys or WASD to move tiles. Press 'Esc' to quit" << endl;
        move = _getch();
        slideTile(pB, move);
        system("CLS");
        check = isBoardSolved(pB, truths);
        printBoard(pB, truths);
        if (check == true)
        {
            cout << "isBoardSolved(): true" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (check == false)
        {
            cout << "isBoardSolved(): false" << endl << endl;
        }
    }

    if (check == true)
    {
        cout << "You won!!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Game ended." << endl;
    }

    cout << "Thanks for playing!" << endl;

    return 0;
}

void initializeBoard(char pB[][3])
{
    int count = 49;
    for (int c = 0; c <= 2; c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d <= 2; d++)
        {
            pB[c][d] = count;
            count++;
        }
    }
    pB[2][2] = '*';
}

void printBoard(char pB[][3], bool truths[][3])
{
    HANDLE hConsole;
    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    cout << endl;
    for (int c = 0; c <= 2; c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d <= 2; d++)
        {
            if (truths[c][d] == true)
            {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN);
            }
            else if (truths[c][d] == false)
            {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN);
            }
            cout << pB[c][d] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE);
}

bool isBoardSolved(char pB[][3], bool truths[][3])
{
    char correctBoard[3][3] = { { '1','2','3' },{ '4','5','6' },{ '7','8','*' } };
    bool proof = true;

    for (int c = 0; c <= 2; c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d <= 2; d++)
        {
            if (pB[c][d] != correctBoard[c][d])
            {
                truths[c][d] = false;
                proof = false;
            }
            else
            {
                truths[c][d] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return proof;
}

void slideTile(char pB[][3], char move)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for (int c = 0; c <= 2; c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d <= 2; d++)
        {
            if (pB[c][d] == '*')
            {
                x = c;
                y = d;
            }
        }
    }

    switch (move)
    {
    case 's':
    case 'S':
    case 80:
        if (x != 0)
        {
            pB[x][y] = pB[x - 1][y];
            pB[x - 1][y] = '*';
        }
        break;
    case 'w':
    case 'W':
    case 72:
        if (x != 2)
        {
            pB[x][y] = pB[x + 1][y];
            pB[x + 1][y] = '*';
        }
        break;
    case 'd':
    case 'D':
    case 77:
        if (y != 0)
        {
            pB[x][y] = pB[x][y - 1];
            pB[x][y - 1] = '*';
        }
        break;
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
    case 75:
        if (y != 2)
        {
            pB[x][y] = pB[x][y + 1];
            pB[x][y + 1] = '*';
        }
        break;
    case 'e':
    case 'E':
        initializeBoard(pB);
    }
}

void scrambleBoard(char pB[][3])
{
    char items[9] = { '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','*' };
    unsigned seed = chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    shuffle(begin(items), end(items), default_random_engine(seed));
    int count = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter == 0)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++)
        {
            if (items[c] > items[c + 1])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if ((counter % 2) == 1)
        {
            shuffle(begin(items), end(items), default_random_engine(seed));
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int c = 0; c <= 2; c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d <= 2; d++)
        {
            pB[c][d] = items[count];
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Boolean comparisons

Instead of:

> ```
> if (isBoardSolved(pB, truths) == true) { ... }
>
> else if (isBoardSolved(pB, truths) == false) { ... }
> ```

The natural way to write is:

```
if (isBoardSolved(pB, truths)) { ... }

else if (!isBoardSolved(pB, truths)) { ... }
```

Apply the same logic everywhere in the code.

#### Unnecessary evaluations

In this code, there are two unnecessary evaluations:

> ```
> if (isBoardSolved(pB, truths) == true)
> {
>     cout << "isBoardSolved(): true" << endl;
> }
> else if (isBoardSolved(pB, truths) == false)
> {
>     cout << "isBoardSolved(): false" << endl;
> }
> ```

The first unnecessary evaluation is `isBoardSolved(pB, truths)`,
assuming the return value hasn't changed between the two calls.
It could call once before the if-else, and reuse the returned value in the two branches.

But you don't need an else-if: `isBoardSolved` returns a `bool`, so it can only have two possible values, simplifying to:

```
if (isBoardSolved(pB, truths))
{
    cout << "isBoardSolved(): true" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "isBoardSolved(): false" << endl;
}
```

Apply the same logic everywhere in the code.

#### Avoid `system`

It's good to avoid calling `system` as much as possible. And it should not be used with relative paths, as that makes the program subject to path injection attacks.

#### Pointless code

This is strange and pointless:

> ```
> bool check = false;
> if (check == true)
> ```

#### Magic numbers

The numbers in these statements are "magic":

```
int count = 49;

// ...

case 's':
case 'S':
case 80:
    // ...
case 'w':
case 'W':
case 72:
    // ...
case 'd':
case 'D':
case 77:
    // ...
case 'a':
case 'A':
case 75:
    // ...
```

They are obviously important for some reason, but it's not clear what they are. You could give them meaning by putting them in constants with descriptive names.

Comment: Not only do constants make it easier to read an understand code, but where the constant is widely used it makes it easier to update a program. An example is that you use 3 in many array declarations, it would be better if 3 was changed to a constant with a meaningful name because you would only have to change the constant in one place to expand the functionality of the program.

Comment: Janos is quite correct about using system(), another reason not to use it is that anytime you make a system call, whether it is system or some other call, your program is swapped out and stops executing until the Operating System gets back to your program.

Comment: Thank you both, I followed you advice and made the suggested changes.